# How to wait for an author to react discord.net

Tags: c#, discord.net

So I am in the middle of writing a bot and I'm trying to make a confirmation thing where author has to proceed by reacting to the message as a confirmation.  I have tried searching around elsewhere but to no avail. Any help would be appreciated.

```
if (File.Exists(Program.channelLocation))
        {
            var msgR = await msg.Channel.SendMessageAsync($"Channel is currently set to: {File.ReadAllText(Program.channelLocation)}. Are you sure you want to change this?");

            var emoji = new Discord.Emoji("✅");

            await msgR.AddReactionAsync(emoji);

            var reactedUsers = await msgR.GetReactionUsersAsync(emoji, 100).FlattenAsync();

            IUser user = msg.Author;

            bool run = true;

            Console.WriteLine("loop started");

            while (run)
            {
                if (reactedUsers.Contains(user))
                {
                    run = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("loop ended");
        }
```

Comment: Hey ! I hope your problem is solved (i'm guessing that it is since you accepted my answer lol) but I just noticed an error in your code: "run = false;" must be placed before "break;" otherwise it won't be executed as break will instantly quit the current iteration !

Comment: yeah, i scrapped that code above and went with the event solution instead. ofcouse the break should be placed after the bool, definitely just a screw-up on my end :)
Thanks for the help tho.

Comment: You're welcome !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [SocketClient.ReactionAdded](https://discord.foxbot.me/latest/api/Discord.WebSocket.BaseSocketClient.html#Discord_WebSocket_BaseSocketClient_ReactionAdded) event.

Here's a basic implementation of the ReactionAdded event (didn't test, might be incorrect):

```
public class Bot {
    public DiscordSocketClient client;

    public Bot() {
        //Initialize your client here...
        client = new DiscordSocketClient(/* ... */);

        client.ReactionAdded += ReactionAdded_Event;
    }

    public void ReactionAdded_Event(Cacheable<IUserMessage, UInt64> message, ISocketMessageChannel channel, SocketReaction reaction)
    {
        //Check if the message is in the right channel, if it's the emoji you want, etc...
    }
}
```

Comment: While the contents of your link seem to answer the question, can I ask you to [edit] your answer and add a code snippet showing how the OP can fix their code to work? Please also read the community Q&A [about flagging answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265553/9363973), pay especially close attention to the *Links to an answer* section

Comment: sure, but OP didn't provide much code so it'll be very generic and will not necessarily apply to his case