# How to add emojis on a bot message and be able to "vote"?

Tags: c#, discord, bots, emoji, vote

I made a MEME command of Discord Bot that posts a list of memes from phpMyAdmin DB. But it is not about that. I want to add specific emojis on that bot message that people could press on those emojis and kinda vote.

It is how it posts:

[image]

It is what I want to do:

[image]

```
    [Command("meme")]
    public async Task meme(CommandContext commandInfo, int id = -1, SocketUserMessage userMsg, string emoteName)
    {
        var description = "";

        MySqlClient.Connect();

        if (id == -1)
        {
            var query = "SELECT * FROM memes;";
            var memeReader = MySqlClient.GetDataReader(query);

            if (memeReader == null) return;

            while (memeReader.Read())
            {
                var memeid = memeReader.GetUInt64("id");
                var title = memeReader.GetString("title");

                description += $"**{memeid}** {title}\n";
            }
        }
        
        var memeEmbed = new DiscordEmbedBuilder()
        {
            Color = DiscordColor.Gold,
            Title = "**The Meme of The Year**",
            Description = description
        };

        var msg = await commandInfo.Channel.SendMessageAsync(embed: memeEmbed);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

### Adding Reactions

Assuming you are using Discord.Net, you need to react to your own message using the `AddReactionAsync` method.

#### Adding Emojis

Emojis are unicode characters. To use them, pass the utf-code (e.g. `"\uD83D\uDC4C"`) as an argument to the constructor of the Emoji` object.

```
await userMsg.AddReactionAsync(new Emoji("\U0001f643"));
```

#### Adding Emotes

An `Emote` is a 'custom Emoji' which can be set by server admins/mods.

As an argument you need to pass a custom Emote string, like this `"<:thonkang:282745590985523200>"`.

A safe wrapper to catch non-existing emotes could look like that (taken from the docs).

```
public async Task ReactWithEmoteAsync(SocketUserMessage userMsg, string escapedEmote)
{
    if (Emote.TryParse(escapedEmote, out var emote))
    {
        await userMsg.AddReactionAsync(emote);
    }
}
```

https://docs.stillu.cc/guides/emoji/emoji.html

### Counting Reactions

As a second step you need to listen to user-events, when they react to your post. This should be done in a separate event handler, as your poll will likely be up for several hours/days.

Here is an example on [how to implement an event handler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59858068/10401159)

You then need to keep track of the reactions and need to associate it with the matching database entry.